# Lambda Calculus and Abstract Reduction systems

Tags: calculus, lambda-calculus

I'm having a hard time understanding Lambda Calculus and I have a two questions that I'm not sure how to do/what they mean. Below we are supposed to use Abstract Reduction Systems.

1. Define an ARS (N×N,→) that has unique normal forms. Argue why your ARS has unique normal forms.
2. Explain how to add and multiply normal forms.

Comment: What is N? An arbitrary set or the set of natural numbers?

Comment: Without more context, question 2. is completely meaningless. What do you mean by adding and multiplying normal forms? Normal forms are just elements of the set that cannot be reduced.